# Slide html content horizontally

Tags: jquery, html

In jQuery you can slide content up or down using "slideIn" and "slideOut" but there is nothing for sliding left or right.

I want to build my own carousel and slide content horizontally.

How would I get content to slide horizontally, sliding the new content into place.
The content has to be any content including images and text mixed together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psuedo code in jQuery would be something like:

```
$('YOURELEMENT').animate({
    left : x
}, TIME);
```

Comment: So the slide up/down functions are just a subset of the animate function?

Comment: I believe so, there is also a JSFiddle I found: http://jsfiddle.net/DcWS2/10/

Comment: @AndroidDev I've updated my answer with an example on how it works internally.

Comment: Ooooh, cheeky commenting on my answer to pimp yours! lol

Comment: Hehe, couldn't resist. Here, have an upvote ;)

Comment: :D Returned the favour. Lots of love in this question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) to make a slide effect horizontally.

```
$('#element').animate(/* properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] */);
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/rs2QK/

How `slideup()` works internally:

```
function (speed, callback) {
    return this.animate({
        height: "hide"
    },
    speed, callback);
}
```

Comment: Cool. Nice website for testing. Learn something new every day. Thanks!